# Building a Views Table to display Commerce order information

Tags: views, commerce, theming

I don't know whether this is possible to achieve in Views, or needs coding.

I want to be able to display Drupal Commerce Orders in a table, one row per order (as in default list provided by Drupal Commerce). I want the first 3-4 columns to show order number, order total, name of purchaser and date. No problem so far, it all works fine.

Now the difficult bit. I then want to have a number of additional columns, one for each category of product (taxonomy), and where an order contains a sale for a line item in each category, I want just the sub-total for that category to appear in the right category column.

For example, an order might contain £10 for a shirt (category/term), and £5 for a scarf (category/term). In the row for that order, I want the £10 to show in the column under the shirt category, and £5 to show in the column under the scarf category.

In spite of much research I cannot figure how to do this, or if it is possible, without coding the table.

Any help would be appreciated.